# Not able to understand how to conditionally format

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need a conditional formatting formula to get the results shown in photo 2.  I need it to be formatted by invoice number.  Each invoice number no matter how many lines needs to be the same color.  I hope that makes sense.  I have no idea where to even start, I did try and "IF" statement but didn't know how to add the true/false part. If anyone can help I would appreciate it.  Thank you for your time.

I tried this formula but not giving proper solution =ISODD(SUM(($D$3:$D$22<>$D$2:$D$21)*(ROW($D$3:$D$22)<=ROW())))

[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHvwV.jpg)
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXKUt.jpg)

Comment: Let me give you a general advise: first create a helper column and try to get the formula working correctly (getting `TRUE` where you want colouring and `FALSE` where not), and use this formula for conditional formatting definition.

Comment: I have tried not workin, could you show me,